# Cloud Functions for Firebase: can you detect app uninstall?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to trigger a Cloud Function when the user uninstalls the app, so that we can clean up the anonymous user realtime database entry?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can detect app uninstall for Android as an [automatically collected Analytics event](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en&ref_topic=6317484) called `app_remove`. Then you could [trigger a Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/extend-with-functions#trigger_a_firebase_analytics_function) to run when that event occurs. You would also need to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) to access the database. Check out some of the [Cloud Functions for Firebase GitHub samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) to see examples of using Analytics triggers and using the Admin SDK. The function could work something like this:

```
exports.appUninstall = functions.analytics.event('app_remove').onLog(event => {
  const user = event.user; // structure of event was changed            
  const uid = user.userId; // The user ID set via the setUserId API.

  // add code for removing data
});
```

Comment: Just on Android for now.

Comment: A few related tips:  The [Cloud Function docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/analytics-events) explain that only events marked as conversion events (done in the Firebase console) will trigger a cloud function.  Also, although the [Events docs](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317522) indicate conversion events are uploaded immediately by the SDK, my preliminary experience is that is not the case.  My cloud function for an event ran about 12 hours after the event occurred.

Comment: It seems the structure of [AnalyticsEvent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.analytics.AnalyticsEvent) has changed since this answer was posted. `user` is now a direct child of `event`, so `const user = event.user;`